# State in parent component not being updated when child component trigger a dispatch reducer successfully redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I facing a weird issue where, the state slice is working fine (backed by unit test and manual testing). But the react selector doesn't seem to have subscribed to it correctly.

The parent component:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Die } from './components/Die'
import './Dice.css'
import { Die as DieModel } from '../../core/dice/entities/Die'
import { RootState } from '../main'

export function Dice() {
  const dice: DieModel[] = useSelector<RootState, DieModel[]>(
    (state) => state.dice.dice,
  )

  const diceElements = dice.map((die) => <Die key={die.id} die={die} />)

  return <div className="dice-container">{diceElements}</div>
}
```

The child component:

```
import './Die.css'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { AppDispatch } from '../../main'
import { holdDie } from '../../../core/dice/diceSlice'

interface DieProps {
  die: {
    id: string
    props: {
      value: number
      isHeld: boolean
    }
  }
}

export function Die({
  die: {
    id,
    props: { isHeld, value },
  },
}: DieProps) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>()

  console.log(id, isHeld, value)
  const isHeldStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isHeld ? `var(--held-die)` : `var(--bright-white)`,
  }

  return (
    <div
      className="die-face"
      style={isHeldStyle}
      onClick={() => dispatch(holdDie(id))}
    >
      <h2 className="die-num">{value}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

*(Props are a bit exotic but don't get disturbed by it)*

Full project codebase can be found here: https://github.com/amehmeto/HexaTenzies

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { Die } from './entities/Die'
import { rollDice } from './usecases/rollDice/rollDice'
import { holdDieReducer } from './usecases/holdDie/holdDie'

export const initialState = {
  dice: [] as Die[],
  loading: false,
  error: null,
}

export const diceSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'dice',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    holdDie: holdDieReducer,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(rollDice.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.dice = action.payload
    })
  },
})

export const { holdDie } = diceSlice.actions
```

When looking at the Redux Toolkit devtool, the state is working as expected on click event. But the prop `isHeld` stays falsy.

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't the state being propagated from parent to child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per discussion in Reactiflux: it appears that the primary problem is use of a mutable class being stored in Redux.  React and Redux both expect plain JS objects and arrays, immutably updated, in order to trigger re-renders:

- https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-mutate-state
- https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions

Related: the whole "ports and adapters" concept really doesn't translate well to a client-side app, and especially React+Redux. that's also going to make this a lot more complex and boilerplate-y than it needs to be.  The "ports and adapters" concept does come from a OOP architecture background.  While you probably *could* do something along those lines without writing any of the code OOP-style, all of the articles you've probably read about "ports and adapters" are most likely assuming use of classes and such.  So, the main advice here would be:

- Switch to storing data as plain JS objects and arrays
- I'd avoid trying to write a client-side app as "ports and adapters".  It's not idiomatic React or Redux, and it's going to make the code more complex.

Additionally, while it's not directly related to the issue: you're writing *wayyyy* more TS types code than you need to.  I'd recommend taking a look at our TS usage instructions at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start to see our recommended TS usage patterns.

Comment: Thanks a lot for those answer. After studying those ressources, I opted for a view model mapper to keep the Ports & Adapters architecture. So the Die class now has this method :

```
  toViewModel(): DieViewModel {
    return {
      id: this.id,
      props: {
        value: this.props.value,
        isHeld: this.props.isHeld,
      },
    }
```

in order to make it serializable.